# EINTR error for semop call

Tags: php, c, semaphore

I am using the following code fragment in a php script to safely update a shared resource.

```
$lock_id = sem_get( ftok( 'tmp/this.lock', 'r'));
sem_acquire($lock_id)
//do something
sem_release($lock_id)
```

When I stress test this code with large number of requests I get an error:

```
Warning: semop() failed acquiring SYSVSEM_SETVAL for key 0x1e: No space left on device in blahblah.php on line 1293
```

php sources show the following code for failed acquiring SYSVSEM_SETVAL

```
while (semop(semid, sop, 3) == -1) {
    if (errno != EINTR) {
        php3_error(E_WARNING, "semop() failed acquiring SYSVSEM_SETVAL for key 0x%x: %s", key, strerror(errno));
        break;
    }
}
```

which means semop fails with EINTR. man page reveals that the semop() system call was interrupted by a signal.

My question is can I safely ignore this error and retry sem_acquire?

**Edit**: I have misunderstood this problem, Pl see the clarification I have posted below.

raj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't ignore the ENOSPC (you're getting something other than EINTR, as the code shows).  You may end up in a busy loop waiting for a resource that you have earlier exhausted.  If you're out of some space somewhere, you want to make sure that you deal with that issue.  ENOSPC generally means you are out of...something.

A couple of random ideas:

I am not an expert on the PHP implementation, but I'd try to avoid calling `sem_get()` each time you want the semaphore.  Store the handle instead.  It may be that some resource is associated with each call to sem_get, and that is where you're running out of space.

I'd make sure to check your error returns on `sem_get()`.  It's a code snippet, but if you were to fail to get the sema4, you would get inconsistent results when trying to `sem_op()` it (perhaps EINTR makes sense)

Answer (score 0):

After posting this question I noticed that I misread the code as `errno` **`==`** `EINTR` and jumped into conclusion. So as bog has pointed out, the error is `ENOSPC` and not `EINTR`. After some digging I located the reason for `ENOSPC`. The number of undo buffers were getting exhausted. I have increased the number of `semmnu` and now the code is running with out issues. I have used `semmni*semms`l as the value of `semmnu`